# preg_replace avoids some tags

Tags: php, curl, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to use cURL to login to a website on a remote domain and later navigate to different pages and make all sorts of data rquests.

**Problem is that on this site some links are relative. This makes my code think that those pages are local (they of course arn't).**

After digging I've realized that I need to use **preg_match** to find and distinct relative links and **preg_replace** to make them absolute url's to the actually existing .js and .css files on that server.

When I run this code it will reaplce avery link as excpected except a few.
What all links should go through is this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popcalendar.css">` 
->
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/popcalendar.css">`. **The rest of the relative links stay as they are. I don't understand why. 
The correctly replaced .css is not even the first one that should be replaced!**

This the PHP script I use to attempt accessing the remote site:

```
<?php
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypass';
$loginUrl = 'http://www.example.com/index.php/';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'uName='.$username.'&uPw='.$password.'&Submit=OK');

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

//Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
//not to print out the results of its query.
//Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
//from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute the request (the login)
$store = curl_exec($ch);

//the login is now done and you can continue to get the
//protected content.

//set the URL to the protected file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/ask_for_info.php');

//execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if (!preg_match('/src="http?:\/\/"/', $result)) {
        $result = preg_replace('/src="(http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/)?([^"]+)"/', "src=\"http://www.example.com/\\3\"", $result);
        echo 'THIS';
    }
    if (!preg_match('/href="http?:\/\/"/', $result)) {
        $result = preg_replace('/href="(http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/)?([^"]+)"/', "href=\"http://www.example.com/\\3\"", $result);
        echo 'THAT';
    }


print_r($result);
?>
```

Checking Google Chrome console while I run the code I get something like this:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://example.com/example.css". login4.php:6
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://example.com/js/prototype.js". login4.php:7
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < prototype.js:1
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://example.com/js/popcalendar3_ajax.js?ver=2". login4.php:9
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

**Any ideas? Thank you for any help provided!**

Comment: You don't use the good tool, using DOMDocument is more easy to do that. As an aside comment, the `if(!preg_match...` are useless, and if you only need to replace relative urls, you must check that links don't begin with `http://` or the host name in the preg_replace pattern.

Comment: The code after `curl_close()` is logically unclear.

Comment: These are already valuable comments to me!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte DOMDocument would force me to use a browser. What if later I want to add this code in a Cron Job? Probably I still need to do the hard way. Secondly, I do want to check the links that begin with `http://` . So I did it wrong. However it did check and replace for all links except 3. I'm looking this up now. Any further suggestions or examples on this? Thanks!

Comment: "DOMDocument would force me to use a browser.", Absolutely not! You can use this with PHP in server side. Keep in mind that the pattern in a preg_replace is already a check, use it.

Comment: @Deadooshka That part kinda works, yet it misses 3 links out of about 15 in the header. I don't understand why so it might actually be illogical as you say. I took that part from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19187444/1863061 Does that help?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'm running through the documentation to find a better example as I clearly have the wrong idea of DOMDocument. Do you know of a better tutorial or doc then the official? http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: You can find several example of use in SO (use tags [php] [dom] to find them) You can take a look here too: http://www.earthinfo.org/xpaths-with-php-by-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example with DOMDocument and XPath:

```
$scheme = 'http';
$host = 'example.com';
$path = '/';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($result);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$xquery = '//a/@href | //img/@src | //script/@src | //link/@href';
$urlAttrNodes = $xpath->query($xquery);

$pattern = '~^(?!https?:// | www\. | // | ' . preg_quote($host)
         . '(?=/|$) )  (\.?/)?~xi';

foreach($urlAttrNodes as $urlAttrNode) {
    $absoluteUrl = preg_replace($pattern, "$scheme://www.$host$path",
                                $urlAttrNode->nodeValue);
    $urlAttrNode->ownerElement->setAttribute($urlAttrNode->name, $absoluteUrl);
}

$result = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Note that the pattern only skip the current host, if needed you can easily add other domains.

Comment: This basically answered the question. It works! Thank you! All I need to figure now out is why does it add a `<script>
    window.location.reload();
  </script>` in result and constantly refreshes the page. However that could be the site's fault. I think of it. Great help really!